# How to get key for value from Hashmap in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, hashmap

I have `HashMap` in Kotlin

```
val map = HashMap<String, String>()
```

I want to know how to get key for a particular value from this `HashMap` without iterating through complete `HashMap`?

Comment: have you tried `filterValues {} ` ?

Comment: no can you please share the code.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-values.html

Comment: No way, values are not indexed. Try using BiMap, which is two-way Map implementation from Guava.

Comment: Do you also need to get a value for a specific key? (if not, your HashMap is backwards).

Comment: @AsadAliChoudhry I would suggest that you first learn the internals of HashMap, then you will realize that hash map isn't what you are looking for.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Using `filterValues {}`

```
val map = HashMap<String, String>()
val keys = map.filterValues { it == "your_value" }.keys
```

And `keys` will be the set of all keys matching the given value

Comment: > without iterating through complete `HashMap`

Comment: The problem with this answer is that you will receive the key value but inside of brace e.g. [A] or [9] instead of A or 9. Just FYI

Comment: Yep I mentioned it will be a set

Comment: so look up speed is independent of size of hash map just like key to value lookup?

Comment: If you want to get rid of the braces `[a]` , you can do `.first()` or .`last()`. You would get `a`

Answer (score 10):

In the worst case (if the matching value doesn't exist in the map), you'll have to iterate over the entire map. However, this code will stop iterating as soon as it finds a match:

```kotlin
val map = mapOf("a" to 1, "b" to 2, "c" to 3)

val matchingKey = map.entries.find { it.value == 3 }?.key

println(matchingKey) // prints "c"
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are constantly **finding keys by values**, a possible solution could be to **reverse the map**, so you can get any key by any value.

For instance:

```
val reversed = map.entries.associate{(k,v)-> v to k}

val resultKey = reversed[value]
```

*Hope it helps!*

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin HashMap, you can use these ways:

```
val hashMap = HashMap<String, String>() // Dummy HashMap.

val keyFirstElement = hashMap.keys.first() // Get key.
val valueOfElement = hashMap.getValue(keyFirstElement) // Get Value.
    
val keyByIndex = hashMap.keys.elementAt(0) // Get key by index.
val valueOfElement = hashMap.getValue(keyByIndex) // Get value.
```